# Memory Management Using Backbone.js - How to reference current views

Tags: memory-management, view, backbone.js, reference

I am using Backbone.js to build my current application.

As a way of navigation via routes, I will replace the new page view in the html as seen below

```
//When new route is called, a new view is created and the html is replaced with the new view
view = new Onethingaday.View.NewView()
$(".main_content_container").html view.render().el
```

I found online that we must do memory management if we are using backbone as seen from this post https://paydirtapp.com/blog/backbone-in-practice-memory-management-and-event-bindings/

My question is

1) Will current view be released totally by just replacing it with a new view (via $(".main_content_container").html view.render().el)?

2) If not, is there a way for me to reference all the views? So that I am able to release, or remove them manually in the program code?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) No, your view and associated events will still exist. You just won't "see" it anymore.

2) Derick Bailey has an excellent [explanation](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/) on handling views and page transitions. The approach outlined at his website is easy to follow, and well explained.

In response to ming yeow's comment:

The short answer is: The view still exists because it is still attached to the DOM element. Re-writing the content of that element using `$('#someTag').html(newView.render().el)` is not the same as calling `oldView.remove()` and `oldView.unbind()` on the element.

Without cleaning up. When you call `$('#someTag').html(newView.render().el)`, the (previous and present) (views and events) are still bound to the `#sometag` element.

This is why when a new view is rendered like so (assuming no clean-up) `$('#someTag').html(newView.render().el)`, if you go to one view, to another, to another, so on and so forth...You will have multiple events and views attached to one element.

Comment: i'd also recommend reading this post on the idea of "regions": http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/12/12/composite-js-apps-regions-and-region-managers/

Comment: @DerickBailey i wish i knew about your work before i started using backbone! would have saved us so much work. But your postings are excellent, thanks a milion for sharing.

Comment: @fbynite I have always been curious - why would the view still exist, unless there is a reference to it somewhere

Comment: @fbynite thanks a million! this helped us understand things quite a bit  better